# Facing problem while running python3 tkinter while python 2.7.11+ exists on my ubuntu

Tags: python3

I am new in python, trying to run a very simple python GUI program just for testing i get the following error

```
$ python3 Desktop.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? I don't think any package from the standard repositories installs anything to /usr/local/lib: did you install python3.5 manually?

Comment: i use ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you may not have TKinter for Python 3 installed. Install Tkinter by running:

```
sudo apt install python3-tk
```